# Max recursion error depth exceeded, python(2.7.5)

Tags: python-2.7

So I am trying to find the least common multiple of the numbers 1 - 20.  For some reason my code exceeds the max recursion depth but I don't understand why.  I just don't see where it gets stuck in the while loop. Also, I know that it doesn't print anything to the console yet.

```
def checking(i,q,w,e):
q = q * w
while i < 20:
    if q % i != 0:
        w += 1.0
        checking(1.0, 20.0, w, [])
    if q % i == 0 and i < 19:
        i += 1
    if q % i == 0 and i == 19:
        e.append(q)
        break
checking(1.0, 20.0, 1.0, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You never change q.  so when `q%i` is not equal to 0, you will never increment i and you will be stuck in the loop for ever.  I think you should re-evaluate your logic here.

Comment: But when `q%1` does not equal 0, w increments by 1, the function is recalled, and q changes to 20 times the new w.  This should continue the increment for q until a situation is found where `if q % i == 0 and i == 19` will be found true.  Or am I missing something?